# MySQL Alter Table Change all fields type using wild card?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a new table by copying an existing table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PeopleView` LIKE `People`
```

I then want to change the data type of all fields using a wild card:

```
ALTER TABLE `PeopleView` CHANGE * * VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
```

**Any ideas how to do this?**

I can do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `PeopleView` CHANGE `FirstName` `FirstName` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
```

But I need a function I can run on many different tables where the field names are all different.

Purpose: Create another table that holds values that are used to decide which columns will be shown or hidden.

**PHP Solution:**

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PeopleView` LIKE `People`");

$cols = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `PeopleView`");

$sql = "ALTER TABLE `PeopleView` ";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cols)) {
  $sql .= "MODIFY `". $row['Field'] ."` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ";
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
mysql_query($sql);
```

**I don't like that I have to run 3 queries to the database, surely there is a better way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then want to change the data type of all fields using a wild card:

You cannot do so. The syntax will only allow you to change the field types by enumerating them and their new definition, one by one.

Comment: Is there a way to generate them automatically within the statement?

Comment: You could get the list of columns from the information_schema and use those to generate the needed statements.

Comment: Ok so generate the list first and then create the statement? I'm using PHP I guess I can run a query to return an array of column names. How do I then format the ALTER TABLE statement? e.g.
ALTER TABLE `PeopleView` CHANGE `FirstName` `FirstName` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, `LastName` `LastName` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
is that correct?

Comment: Basically yeah. And execute them one by one. (Though, note that you can alter multiple columns in the same statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Added solution, I am sure it can be done a better way but this works for now.